# Boyer-Moore Algorithm string comparison

Tags: algorithms

Construct a pattern of length 8, over the alphabet a, b, such that the number of comparisons in Boyer-Moore Algorithm is as large as possible. No string is given!

I don't quite understand how to start this question, any tips/starting points ?